# How to take input 128 bit unsigned integer in c++

Tags: c++, 128-bit

I am new to c++. I want to take input a unsigned 128 bit integer using scanf and print it using printf. As I am new to c++ , I only know these two methods for input output. Can someone help me out?

Comment: @Walter everything in C is part of C++ as well. If you want to suggest a better method that's fine, but the way your comment was phrased isn't very helpful.

Comment: You very possibly don't even have a 128 bit integer type in C/C++. I think you're going to need to look into if there are math libraries that suit your needs.

Comment: What did you try? What precisely is the question?

Comment: @MarkRansom rubbish, not everything in C is part of C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use boost, but this library set must be installed yourself:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;

   uint128_t v = 0;

   std::cin >> v; // read 
   std::cout << v << std::endl; // write

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: is adding boost just for 128 bit integer appropriate?

Comment: @Roozbehhz depends on the need and lack of other options

Comment: @Roozbehhz boost helps to solve many tasks in modern c++ applications, so from practical point of view, boost must become usual tool for practicing programmers, including beginners

Comment: Boost's a big hammer, but it is a useful hammer.

Comment: @user4581301 boost is set of hammers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get along without boost, you can store the value into two uint64_t as such:

```cpp
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

uint64_t high = 0, low = 0, tmp;
for(char c : input)
{
    high *= 10;
    tmp = low * 10;
    if(tmp / 10 != low)
    {
        high += ((low >> 32) * 10 + ((low & 0xf) * 10 >> 32)) >> 32;
    }
    low = tmp;
    tmp = low + c - '0';
    high += tmp < low;
    low = tmp;
}
```

Printing then, however, gets more ugly:

```cpp
std::vector<uint64_t> v;
while(high | low)
{
    uint64_t const pow10 = 100000000;
    uint64_t const mod = (((uint64_t)1 << 32) % pow10) * (((uint64_t)1 << 32) % pow10) % pow10;
    tmp = high % pow10;
    uint64_t temp = tmp * mod % pow10 + low % pow10;
    v.push_back((tmp * mod + low) % pow10);
    low = low / pow10 + tmp * 184467440737 + tmp * /*0*/9551616 / pow10 + (temp >= pow10);
    high /= pow10;
}
std::vector<uint64_t>::reverse_iterator i = v.rbegin();
while(i != v.rend() && *i == 0)
{
    ++i;
}
if(i == v.rend())
{
    std::cout << 0;
}
else
{
    std::cout << *i << std::setfill('0');
    for(++i; i != v.rend(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(8) << *i;
    }
}
```

Above solution works up to (including)

```cpp
340282366920938463463374516198409551615
= 0x ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ad06 1410 beff
```

Above, there is an error.

Note: pow10 can be varied, then some other constants need to be adjusted, e. g. `pow10 = 10`:

```cpp
low = low / pow10 + tmp * 1844674407370955161 + tmp * 6 / pow10 + (temp >= pow10);
```

and

```cpp
std::cout << std::setw(1) << *i; // setw also can be dropped in this case
```

Increasing results in reducing the maximum number for which printing still works correctly, decreasing raises the maximum. With pow10 = 10, maximum is

```cpp
340282366920938463463374607431768211425
= ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffe1
```

I don't know where the error for the very highest numbers comes from, yet, possibly some unconsidered overflow. Any suggestions appreciated, then I'll improve the algorithm. Until then, I'd reduce pow10 to 10 and introduce a special handling for the highest 30 failing numbers:

```cpp
std::string const specialValues[0] = { /*...*/ };
if(high == 0xffffffffffffffff && low > 0xffffffffffffffe1)
{
    std::cout << specialValues[low - 0xffffffffffffffe2];
}
else
{
    /* ... */
}
```

So at least, we can handle all valid 128-bit values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **from_string_128_bits** and **to_string_128_bits** with 128 bits unsigned integers in C :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__uint128_t from_string_128_bits(const char *str) {
    __uint128_t res = 0;
    for (; *str; res = res * 10 + *str++ - '0');
    return res;
}

static char *to_string_128_bits(__uint128_t num) {
    __uint128_t mask = -1;
    size_t a, b, c = 1, d;
    char *s = malloc(2);
    strcpy(s, "0");
    for (mask -= mask / 2; mask; mask >>= 1) {
        for (a = (num & mask) != 0, b = c; b;) {
            d = ((s[--b] - '0') << 1) + a;
            s[b] = "0123456789"[d % 10];
            a = d / 10;
        }
        for (; a; s = realloc(s, ++c + 1), memmove(s + 1, s, c), *s = "0123456789"[a % 10], a /= 10);
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    __uint128_t n = from_string_128_bits("10000000000000000000000000000000000001");
    n *= 7;
    char *s = to_string_128_bits(n);
    puts(s);
    free(s); // string must be freed
    // print 70000000000000000000000000000000000007
}
```